# Why does the application look different after launching than in designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, oop, responsive-design

I have a little question. I'm new to WPF and a strange thing happened to me. In the designer everything looks fine, but as soon as I start the application, a piece ,,cuts off"(via.photo) and it looks pretty bad. Could it be that the application is not responsive?
[image: How does it look like after starting]

[image: How does it look like in XAML designer]

**My XAML code:**

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem" 
                 Visibility="Hidden" 
                 x:Name="Home_Page" 
                 Background="{x:Null}" 
                 BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Height="Auto"
                 Width="Auto"
                 >

            <Border 
                Background="Black"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Width="1340" 
                Height="1100"
                CornerRadius="20"
                >
                <Border
                    Background="White" 
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    Height="700"
                    Width="500"
                    Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   
                    >
                    <Grid 
                        
                        >
                        <TextBlock
                            Text="Welcome"
                            Width="200"
                            Height="200"
                            Foreground="Black"
                            FontSize="50" FontFamily="/Peel_App;component/Fonts/#Kashima Brush Demo"
                            
                            >

                        </TextBlock>

                    </Grid>

                </Border>

            </Border>

        </TabItem>
```

After what I edited app:[image: note that I set Height and Width of Window also to auto and every Grid as well]

Comment: The size in the designer is not the real size when run. Try to change the size and run it again (it might have to look wrong in the designer).

Comment: Try to set the size of the Window

Comment: So should I go by what it looks like after launch?

Comment: You should go with Arthur's answer. Try not to use hard coded numbers in the margin to set x,y position on the screen. Using Grids with column and row definitions and panels to make your layout will save you from headaches like these.

Comment: Make sure the Zoom setting is set to 100% https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few issues:

1. You're hardcoding the `Margin` values to position your controls. Instead, you should use proper panels (`DockPanel`, `WrapPanel`, and `Grid`). Use `Margin` property to set **margin**, not a position.
2. Use `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` properties to position your elements, thus your UI would be more responsive and user-friendly.
3. To be able to view, how your window and its content would look like - try to set `d:DesignHeght` and `d:DesignWidth` properties on a window. Try to Google how to use them.

In the end, your code should look like following:

```
<TabItem Header="TabItem"
         Visibility="Hidden"
         x:Name="Home_Page"
         Background="{x:Null}"
         BorderBrush="{x:Null}"> <!-- Properties order is a bit confusing, it is better to order them by priority, or just alphabetically. -->
    <Border Background="Black">
        <Border Background="White"
                CornerRadius="20"
                Margin="0,0,93,118"> <!-- Should it have such values? Maybe just somenthing like Margin="0 0 90 120"? -->
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Welcome"
                           Foreground="Black"
                           FontSize="50" 
                           FontFamily="/Peel_App;component/Fonts/#Kashima Brush Demo"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</TabItem>
```

Comment: Hello, I edited my question

Comment: @Radek_Dom, looks like you have set the `HorizontalAlignment` - `Center` or `Left` on one of your parental controls. Please check.